# Current software sources for damn small linux

Tags: linux, debian

I have installed damn small linux and i now want to install gearman on it.DSL has a single source enabled on the version of dsl i have installed and that is

> deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-archive/debian woody main contrib
>   non-free

I have made this assumption that gearman can be found in one of the very many debian sources available but that would be a huge task to figure out where to find that one package and besides gearman might have dependencies.

Are there sources i can add that can help me find the package i want quickly and more common tools like the most recent versions of php and apache?.

Thank you.

Comment: ummm woody is something like three versions ago (I'm not sure coz I use arch).  Maybe you need to upgrade your dsl install before adding things.

Comment: I have arch and i was unable to install it.I am planning on building gearman dependencies from source.I however had found gearmn package on arch.

Comment: hmmmm.  I'd expect installing arch to be easier than building programs including dependencies from source.

Comment: ArchLinux without AIF is a lot of pain IMHO.I am going to try installing a version with AIF and hope that i shall be able to install newer packages.